# snowflake - Purge User - Alert Role Owner that user is not active for long time

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Agenda - to notify role owner that user is inactive for long time.

I am creating a procedure where i need to capture user inactive for more than 90 days and to capture his role and role owners and need to compile and send list to role owner and role owner will take action later.

below is the procedure I developed

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "Notify_Owner_Inactive_Users"()
    RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    EXECUTE AS CALLER
    AS '
    var users = "SHOW USERS;" ;
    var users_drtemp = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: users });
    users_drtemp.execute();
    
    
    var inactive_users = snowflake.createStatement(
      
      { sqlText: 
        `
        SELECT "login_name",DATEDIFF("Day","last_success_login",CURRENT_DATE) as not_login_since,owner FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))
         where DATEDIFF("Day","last_success_login",CURRENT_DATE) > 90 or last_success_login is null 
         and "disabled"='false'
         and "snowflake_lock"='false'
         ;
    `
    }
    );
    var rs_inactive_users= inactive_users.execute();
    
    while (rs_inactive_users.next()) 
    
    {
    try{
           var user_name = rs_inactive_users.getColumnValue(1);
           var owner_name = rs_inactive_users.getColumnValue(3);
           
    var roles = "SHOW ROLES;" ;
    var users_Roles = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: roles });
    users_Roles.execute();
    
    var owner_email_id = snowflake.createStatement(
      
      { sqlText: 
        `
        
        select distinct split_part(b.data,':',2) as Owner_Email from (
        select a.value::string as data from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())),
        lateral flatten(input=>split(comment,',')) a) b where b.data like '%Owner%';
        
         ;
    `
    }
    );
    var rs_owner_email= owner_email_id.execute();
    
    while (rs_owner_email.next()) 
    
    {
    try{
           var email_address = rs_owner_email.getColumnValue(1);
           
    catch(err)
          {
                 return("Job Failure");   
          }
         
    }
    
    return("Job Completed")
    ';
```

i need to take user list and map to role owners and send an email to owner
Can someone develop on top of it

Comment: When you run this procedure, what's missing?

Comment: Procedure is incomplete,need to map users to role owner and send an email to role owner

Comment: If a user is granted to multiple roles, you'd be notifying all of those role owners?  The procedure you have now selects the users and finds the role owners, but you need to join your users to their roles, which exists in the `GRANTS_TO_USERS` view in `ACCOUNT_USAGE`.  Your procedure is then going to need to call an External Function to actually send an email.

Comment: Hi mike ,yes need to notify all role owners,this procedure  will capture role and role owner(in variable I mentioned as a owner ) and also role owner email address .

Comment: Probably Stack Overflow will not write the full script you need to write, but we can help with any part that is not working. Can you split this question in new questions, focusing each on concrete problems you'd like us to help?

Comment: felipe,if i split ,will miss the flow,i dont know how to explain

Comment: What does the `rs_owner_email` do? Is that somehow connected to an external function that sends an email? What part do you need help completing?